# Definition of drift

Tags: analytical-chemistry, terminology

What does **drift** actually mean in analytical chemistry? I can't find the exact definition and now am not sure whether my intuitive understanding of it is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [*International Vocabulary of Metrology*](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/guides/vim.html) (JCGM 200 as well as ISO/IEC Guide 99), *instrumental drift* is defined as

> continuous or incremental change over time in indication, due to changes in metrological properties of a measuring instrument

with the note that

> Instrumental drift is related neither to a change in a quantity being measured nor to a change of any recognized influence quantity.

Thus, instrumental drift is caused by a continuous or incremental change in the value of an *unmeasured* influence quantity during the period of repeated observations.

The consideration of instrumental drift is important when evaluating uncertainty in measurement. According to the [*Guide to the Expression of Uncertainty in Measurement*](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/guides/gum.html) (JCGM 100 as well as ISO/IEC Guide 98), it must be asked whether all of the influences that are assumed to be random really are random. If there is a sufficient number of observations, the arithmetic means of the results of the first and second halves of the period and their experimental standard deviations may be calculated and the two means compared with each other in order to judge whether the difference between them is statistically significant and thus if there is an effect varying with
time.